# Erro declaração Android-Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Queria saber porque meu android studio esta dando esses erros nas declarações, essa print ai é de um projeto novo, declaração feita pelo próprio android studio esta dando erro.

Comment: Não apareceu o print na pergunta

Comment: acabei de editar... tinha esquecido de colocar a imagen

Answer (score 0):

Por favor tente os seguintes passos:

1 opção Vá até o Menu > File > "Invalidade Caches / Restart"

Caso não dê certo.

2 opção Vá até o Menu > Build > clean Project. Depois que finalizar o processo vá novamente em Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: desculpe não deu certo, ainda continua.

Comment: Qual erro ele mostra quando voce sobrepoe o mouse nas palavras em vermelho?

Comment: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/7901/QAQLCC.png

Comment: Certo. Como o Invalidade não deu certo. Faça o seguinte: Feche o projeto. Vá até o diretório do projeto e apague a pasta .gradle e .idea

Comment: Depois abra novamente o projeto aguarde rebuildar e comente aqui se deu certo ou não.

Comment: deu o seguinte erro:ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-login:100.1.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Veja se o topico no link te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670842/failed-to-resolve-com-facebook-androidfacebook-login4-5/46671052